# Как принять данные с GPS трекера на веб сервере под Windows?

Tags: php, windows, gps

Я долго искал, но нашёл лишь одну единственную статью во всём интернете, о том как принимать данные с GPS трекера и перенаправлять их в PHP скрипт: [slava.uma.ru/?a=page&id=142](http://slava.uma.ru/?a=page&id=142)

Проблема в том, что она написана для программы xinetd, работающей только под линуксом, мне же нужно развернуть приём данных на windows.

Скиньте нужную мне статью или помогите разобраться с вопросом, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел несколько статей ([англ](http://www.gps-server.net/getting-started-with-gps-tracking)., [хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/20076/)., [OpenGTS](https://habrahabr.ru/post/129395/), [рус3](http://phpclub.ru/talk/threads/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%82-gps-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0.78926/)).

По большому счёту у Вас должен быть слушатель (сервер), который принимает по TCP/IP данные из устройства.

Вариантов решения может быть несколько:

1. Создать свой сокет сервер, который будет запущен как служба и слушать по определённому порту. А GPS трекер по (TCP/IP) должен будет обращаться к Вашему серверу по ip  и передавать данные.Примеры создания php сервера ([рус](https://myrusakov.ru/php-socket-server.html), [рус](http://petukhovsky.com/simple-web-socket-on-php-from-very-start/), [англ](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/418814/Socket-Programming-in-PHP), [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/sockets.examples.php), [что такое сокеты](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.sockets.php))
2. Использовать готовый слушатель [Inetd](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb463195.aspx).

Что касается Windows. Советую делать зразу на linus. Если у Вас windows, то, наверное, выливайте всё на хостинг (должен быть уже слушатель) и пробуйте через хостинг подключаться.

Готовых слушателей для windows не нашёл

Как вариант - вы можете установить virtualBox на него ubuntu поставить и там установить xinetd.

Если надумаете писать демон на php, то вот ещё одна [статья](http://mithrandir.ru/professional/php/php-daemons.html)

Comment: OpenGTS - это разве не Java приложение? Я только с PHP знаком. Мой GPS трекер не умеет обращаться по веб протоколам, а значит и к серверу напрямую, потому я не понял идеи с вебсокетом. Мне как раз нужен посредник или слушатель, который будет формировать http запрос к php скрипту на сервере. У xinetd есть windows аналог - cygwin, но я не нашёл ни одной статьи по его настройке, как в приведённой мной статье. Задачу мне нужно выполнить на windows.

Comment: @Diskyp нет, я не имел ввиду вебсокет, а просто сокет

Comment: @Diskyp тут необходим уровень ниже - TCP/IP. PHP работает через HTTP, но можно создать свой слушатель TCP/IP на php. B тут нужны сокеты, это не веб-сокеты.

Comment: я не знаю, не задавался таким вопросом, мобильные устройства в моём проекте не фигурируют. Мой трекер умеет только отправлять данные на указанный ip и tcp порт, вот собственно и всё.

Comment: То есть на php можно написать слушателя и клиента (а вы будете обращаться по ip адресу к слушателю), а этот слушатель должен сохранять или передавать данные в php клиент

Comment: @Diskyp извините, я там кинул одну сслыку на веб сокеты - это не то. Нужны TCP/IP http://php.net/manual/ru/sockets.examples.php

Comment: Нда, звучит как трудоёмкое изобретение велосипеда, я надеялся на просто аналог xinetd и какую-нибудь внятную статью по его настройке.

Comment: @Diskyp просто смотрите по какому ip вы будете отправлять данные? Как устройство сможет определить Ваш локальный ip? Скорее всего Вам надо будет внешний ip сервера

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55588/discussion-between-konstantin-okhotnick-and-diskyp).

Comment: @Diskyp я к чему веду. Локально будет проблематично настроить передачу данных от устройства к серверу. Вам надо будет удалённый сервер. А удалённый сервер  (апач или нджинкс) будет на linux. Вот на него и надо ставить xinetd

Comment: трекеру смской отправляется настройка с нужным ip и портом, там-то всё схвачено. Я завтра попробую воспользоваться вашей статьёй про сокеты и затем отпишусь о результатах, спасибо за помощь. Однако от статьи для cygwin или чего-нибудь такого я бы по-прежнему не отказался, так что пока оставлю вопрос открытым.

Comment: удалённый сервер с апачем у меня уже есть, он стоит на винде.